# Передать значения формы через AJAX в PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Как передать данные формы в php при помощи AJAX?

Нужно передать двумерный массив ( vote[] )
Именно в этом загвоздка.

Если передавать вот так,

```
data: {
  array: $("#form").serialize()
}
```

То получается не то:

> vote%5B%5D=значение

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" value="" name="first">
  <input type="text" value="" name="second">

  <input type="text" value="" name="vote[]">
  <input type="text" value="" name="vote[]">
  <input type="text" value="" name="vote[]">

  <input type="submit" value="Передать в php" name="submit">
</form>
```

Подтолкните на правильное направление. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Немного не понятно, что вообще там отправляется и как.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('ключ'  , *сюда кинь свой массив*);
```

И ajax`ом отправляй объект fd